# I want select card by javascript and duplicate that 10 times

Tags: javascript

```js
function test() {
            const body = document.querySelector('body');
            const card = document.querySelector('.card');
            const copy = card.cloneNode(true);
            let array = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                array.push(card);
               body.appendChild(array[i]);
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="https://media.vlpt.us/post-images/godori/c475ccb0-d529-11e8-a864-6fe678a235c1/js.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want select card element by javascript and duplicate that 10 times by for loop.
this by angular framework simple but pure js difficult
please help me to done.
thank you .

Comment: Who is calling `test`

Comment: Have you tried querySelectorAll(‘.card’)? That will make a node list of all objects with class of card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
        function test() {
            const body = document.querySelector('body');
            const card = document.querySelector('.card');
                for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    let array = [];
                    let newCard = card.cloneNode(true);
                    card.after(newCard);
                    array.push(newCard);
            }
        }
        test();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="https://media.vlpt.us/post-images/godori/c475ccb0-d529-11e8-a864-6fe678a235c1/js.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```